# it shows uncaught referenceError :$ is not defined. whats the exact matter cant understand

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script type="application/json" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <style>
                th{
                    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
                    font: bold;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                td{
                    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
                    text-align: center;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <section>
                <h1>Json data to HTML table</h1>
                <table id="JsonTable" style="table-layout: auto; border: 2px solid black;">
                    <tr style="border: 1px solid red;">
                        <th>UserID</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Body</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",function(data){
                            var task='_';
                            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                                task +='<tr>';
    
                                task +='<td>'+ value.userId +'</td>';
    
                                task +='<td>'+ value.id +'</td>';
    
                                task +='<td>'+ value.title +'</td>';
    
                                task +='<td>'+ value.body +'</td>';
    
                                task +='</tr>';
                            })
                            $('#JsonTable').append(task);
                        })
                    })
                </script>
            </section>
        </body>enter code here
    </html>
```

What's the matter I can't understand. It shows error on the 30th line:

> uncaught referenceError :$ is not defined.

I tried finding the solution but still its giving the error. please help what to do. I am a fresher in `jQuery` and `Ajax`.

Comment: You don't need to use the type attribute anymore on html5 on a script that is JavaScript. jQuery is not JSON either as other people have mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you are including the script with the type "application/json". Try to remove the type attribute on your script tag.

Answer (score 1):

`type="application/json"`?